# belongs_to with a custom class_name not producing proper foreign key in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to

I am updating an application to Rails 3 and I am having trouble creating a custom foreign key.  I have something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
...
end

class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @products = current_user.products
  end
end
```

The view:

```
<%- @products.each do |p| -%>
    <%= p.created_at %><br />
<%- end -%>
```

I get this error in my Rails log:

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'products.user_id' in 'where clause': SELECT     `products`.* FROM       `products` WHERE     (`products`.user_id = 1)
```

It should see the `belongs_to :owner` and look for a foreign key called `owner_id`.  I even tried explicitly setting the foreign key and that does not work.  I also checked lighthouse for a possible Rails 3 bug but no luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify the foreign key on the `has_many :products` association, it does not automagically know that it mirrors the `belongs_to :owner`.

This should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
...
end
```

From the rails docs:

> **:foreign_key**
>
> Specify the foreign key
> used for the association. By default
> this is guessed to be the name of this
> class in lower-case and "_id"
> suffixed. So a Person class that makes
> a has_many association will use
> "person_id" as the default
> :foreign_key..

Comment: this worked but i guess it's a bit strange that i didn't have to do it with my Rails 2 app.  not sure it would be considered a bug

Comment: It should be the same in Rails 2. :)

Comment: I have two columns on my table that reference the User table.  Do you know how I would set up the reference?  I can't just say owner_id as suggested above because I need Owner and SubmittingUser.  Thanks!